# Post request returning empty or encoded

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request to an api but I get an empty string as response or an encoded/encrypted one I dont understand well why(both respones i get a 200 OK repsonse). this is from the page I am trying to replicate the request: [Request Header from website][image: 1].
thats the payload [the payload][image: 2]
and this is my code:

```
headers = {
'authority': 'node1.web3api.com',
'method': 'POST',
'path' : '/',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
'content-length': '252',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'origin' :'https://etherscan.io',
'referer': 'https://etherscan.io/',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Microsoft Edge";v="96"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62'
}

payload = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_call", "params": [
    {"from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
     "data": "0xc87b56dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
     "to": "0xd754937672300ae6708a51229112de4017810934"}, "latest"]}

with requests.session() as session:
    session.get('https://etherscan.io/address/0xd754937672300ae6708a51229112de4017810934#readContract')
    r = requests.post('https://node1.web3api.com/', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print(r.text)
    print(r.content)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `session.post` rather than `requests.post`? Also, I would suggest you use `.post(..., json=payload)`, rather than `.post(..., data=json.dumps(payload))`.

Comment: thx I will try it out

Comment: thank you so much, the json=payload helped me out and seesion.post to even it wasnt needed i did request.post without cookie and still worked thx again ahaha was flipping out haha